# Add parameters to a given URL in Python

Tags: python, urllib, urllib3

I want to add the following parameters:

`params= {'Context' : { "Country":"US", "Region":"US", "Language":"en", "Segment":"dhs", "CustomerSet":"19"}, 'itemIdentifiers' : ['210-amsr','320-9704']}`

to the base URL = `https://www.catalogue.com/getdetail?`

so that the final URL looks like this: `https://www.catalogue.com/getdetail?Context={"Country":"US","Region":"US","Language":"en","Segment":"dhs","CustomerSet":"19"}&itemIdentifiers=210-amsr,320-9704`

I've tried the following approach:
`api_url = url+parse.urlencode(params, doseq=True)`

but I end up with: `https://www.catalogue.com/getdetail?Context=Country&Context=Region&Context=Language&Context=Segment&Context=CustomerSet&itemIdentifiers=210-amsr&itemIdentifiers=320-9704`

Comment: Have you tried this yourself yet? How about using the requests library?

Comment: I've tried the following approach: `api_url = url+parse.urlencode(params, doseq=True)`

but I end up with:  `https://www.catalogue.com/getdetail?Context=Country&Context=Region&Context=Language&Context=Segment&Context=CustomerSet&itemIdentifiers=210-amsr&itemIdentifiers=320-9704`

I have also tried the request library but I am getting similar results.

Comment: How do you feel about using [requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/) - it makes all of this much more pleasant. This way you wouldn't need to add it to your URL, but simply pass your `params` dict as the `params` arg to your request function.

Comment: I tried that, and it worked, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

The [requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/) can handle this for you:

```py
import requests

base_url = r"https://www.catalogue.com/getdetail"
params= {
    "Context" : { 
        "Country": "US", 
        "Region" : "US", 
        "Language" : "en", 
        "Segment" : "dhs", 
        "CustomerSet" : "19"
     }, 
     "itemIdentifiers" : ['210-amsr', '320-9704'],
}

requests.get(base_url, params=params)
```